# Yes/Maybe/No buttons not appearing for ICS calendar visualforce email attachment

Tags: visualforce, email-template, messaging-attachment

**Background**

I am using `<messaging:attachment` to generate a `.ics` calendar invite as an attachment as part of a `visualforce` email template.

```
<messaging:attachment filename="invite.ics" renderAs="text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST">
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Salesforce Inc//NONSGML//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=GMT:<apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ}"><apex:param value="{!relatedTo.Interview_Date_Time__c}"/></apex:outputText>
DTEND;TZID=GMT:<apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ}"><apex:param value="{!relatedTo.Interview_Date_Time__c}"/></apex:outputText>
DTSTAMP:<apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ}"><apex:param value="{!TODAY()}"/></apex:outputText>
ORGANIZER;CN={!relatedTo.Owner.Email}:mailto:{!relatedTo.Owner.Email}
UID:{!relatedTo.Interview_Number__c}@example.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN={!relatedTo.Application__r.Email__c};X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:{!relatedTo.Application__r.Email__c}
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE;CN={!relatedTo.Owner.Email};X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:{!relatedTo.Owner.Email}
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:-{!relatedTo.Interview_Number__c}
CREATED:<apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ}"><apex:param value="{!TODAY()}"/></apex:outputText>
DESCRIPTION:<apex:outputText value="Interview with X"/>
LAST-MODIFIED:<apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ}"><apex:param value="{!TODAY()}"/></apex:outputText>
LOCATION:Zoom screen share
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:<apex:outputText value="Interview with X"/>
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
</messaging:attachment>
```

Unfortunately, the `Yes`, `Maybe` and `No` buttons don't appear.

What I want to see is:

[image]

But what I get is:

[image]

**Questions**

1. Why aren't the buttons appearing?
2. What can I do to fix it?